# Apache Camel: Copy File in different folder in same SFTP

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

Want to copy file in different folder in same FTP Server. (Not move but copy only)

Following is code:

```
 private static String fromSftpComponent() {
    return "sftp://transit.evy.com/Hrm/test/From_HRM"
            + "?username=Hrm"
            + "&password=PqIy" // Stored on wildfly server
            + "&download=true" 
            + "&reconnectDelay=10000"
            + "&delay=100000"
            + "&fileName=Integrator_3.xml";


 private static String toSftpComponent {
    return "sftp://transit.evy.com/Hrm/dev/From_HRM"
            + "?username=HRM"
            + "&password=PqIy" // Stored on wildfly server
            + "&fileName=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.xml";
}


ROUTE

public void configure() throws Exception {

                from(fromSftpComponent())
                    .log("CHU" + header("CamelFileName"))
                    .to(toSftpComponent())
                    .end().log("Written to output file");
```

When i try to run the code it connects to SFTP 1 and then print CHU log and then does not copy it to destination and keep on disconnecting and reconnecting destination.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `noop=true` option. Check out the documentation [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html#_query_parameters_92_parameters)

---

> noop (consumer) If true, the file is not moved or deleted in any way.
>   This option is good for readonly data, or for ETL type requirements.
>   If noop=true, Camel will set idempotent=true as well, to avoid
>   consuming the same files over and over again

---

Something like this will do

```
from("file:source?noop=true")
        .to("file:destination");
```